# How to correctly handle/ get correct JSON response with PHP API and AngularJS 2 services?

Tags: php, mysql, api, angular, typescript

Here is my problem with my backend which is MySQL. One query is giving me this set of data

`{"candidat":[{"ID":1,"nom":"Danny","prenom":"Hariot","parti":"Quamba","departement":"Ukraine","commune":"Chapayeve"},{"ID":2,"nom":"Shari","prenom":"Adamkiewicz","parti":"Babbleopia","departement":"Sweden","commune":"Täby"}]`

A array of arrays , and I wanna access to the nested arrays for my Angular project. I mean this part

```
[{"ID":1,"nom":"Danny","prenom":"Hariot","parti":"Quamba","departement":"Ukraine","commune":"Chapayeve"},{"ID":2,"nom":"Shari","prenom":"Adamkiewicz","parti":"Babbleopia","departement":"Sweden","commune":"Täby"}]
```

Here is my component

```
import { IPaeComponent } from './paeI';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms/src/directives';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CandidatService } from './paeServices';

@Component({
    selector : 'pae-app',
    moduleId : module.id,  
    templateUrl : 'pae1.html'
})

export class PaeComponent implements IPaeComponent{
    prog1 : string ="Programme d'Appui aux Elections";
    progName1 : string ="Enquête sur les candidats";
    searchbar : string ='';
    progEl1 : string ="Listes des candidats ciblés";
    candInfo : any [];
    filter : string;

    candidats : IPaeComponent;
    errorMessage : string;

    constructor (private _candidatService : CandidatService){

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this._candidatService.getCandidatInfo()
            .subscribe(candidats => this.candInfo = candidats,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

}
```

My services:

```
import { IPaeComponent } from './paeI';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response , Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

@Injectable()
export class CandidatService {
    private _candidatUrl ='http://localhost/CRUD/api.php/candidat?transform=1';

    constructor(private _http : Http){

    }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////CRUD///////////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////   





    getCandidatInfo() : Observable<IPaeComponent[]>{
        return this._http.get(this._candidatUrl)
        .map((response : Response)=><IPaeComponent[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All '+ JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error : Response){
            console.error(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }

      addCandidatInfo (body: Object): Observable<IPaeComponent[]> {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this._http.post(this._candidatUrl, body, options) // ...using post request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }   


    updateCandidatInfo (body: Object): Observable<IPaeComponent[]> {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this._http.put(`${this._candidatUrl}/${body['id']}`, body, options) // ...using put request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }   


    removeInfo (id:string): Observable<IPaeComponent[]> {
        return this._http.delete(`${this._candidatUrl}/${id}`) // ...using put request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }   
}
```

And what it looks like when I debug in my browser:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the array from your response:

```
getCandidatInfo() : Observable<IPaeComponent[]>{
    return this._http.get(this._candidatUrl)
    .map((response : Response)=><IPaeComponent[]> response.json().candidat) // here
    .do(data => console.log('All '+ JSON.stringify(data)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this._candidatService.getCandidatInfo()
        .subscribe(candidats => {
          this.candInfo = candidats.candidat;
          // if you want get value from particular index
          cosnole.log(this.candInfo[0]);

          // Or you can iterate loop to get each value
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```